# How do I change the light/dark mode icon in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

Docusaurus has a nice, minimal sun and moon for their light/dark mode button: https://docusaurus.io/

But our Docusaurus page automatically uses a toggle button that shows the moon emoji  and the sun emoji . They're cute, but don't fit with our site's overall look.

I couldn't find specifics about this in the Docusaurus user docs or in their API docs. I went into the GitHub repo for Docusaurus and checked out their `css` files as well as their `config.js` file. I did the same for some other companies who use Docusaurus, but I can't find the code that generates the light/dark mode button.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Docusarus 2.0.0-beta.17 `switchConfig` [was deprecated](https://docusaurus.io/changelog/2.0.0-beta.17#-breaking-change).

As [related PR says](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/6771): `colorMode.switchConfig` is deprecated. If you want to customize the icons for light and dark mode, swizzle `IconLightMode`, `IconDarkMode`, or `ColorModeToggle` instead.